# Redux: How to pass an ID to the mapStateToProps function to get from the state an entity with that ID

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this container component:

```
const TodoListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoListComponent)
```

I call it in this way:

```
    let TodoListHtml = document.getElementById('TodoList');

    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <TodoListContainer id={TodoListHtml.dataset.id}/>
        </Provider>,
        TodoListHtml
    )
```

As you can see I pass the container the prop `id=TodoListHtml.dataset.id` that is the ID of the list I'd like to render.

My `state` is shaped this way:

```
state {
    TodoLists: {
        entities: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                name: 'The name of the list'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, my container component should get from the `state` the TodoList `state.TodoLists.entities.1`

My pseudo-code:

```
// Container.js
const getTodoList = (state, id) => {
    return state.TodoLists.entities.1
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, id) => {
    return {
        todoList: getTodoList(state, id)
    }
}

export default const TodoListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoListComponent)
```

And this is the code that renders the container component

```
// Todolist.html: The html calling the container component
let TodoListHtml = document.getElementById('TodoList');

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <TodoListContainer id={TodoListHtml.dataset.id}/>
    </Provider>,
    TodoListHtml
)
```

**The question is: how can I pass the ID?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MapStateToProps` takes `ownProps` as the second argument, you would pass the id a props to the Container component and then you do get it like

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        todoList: getTodoList(state, ownProps.id)
    }
}
```